# Access Token Curl

Tags: api, curl, authorization, token

On this website:
https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize

Under Get Access Token
It says "Open a terminal and run the following curl command, replacing oauth2-client-id and oauth2-client-secret with the OAuth2 Client ID and Client Secret from your GCP Credentials, and authorization-code with the code you receive in the previous step:"

I have repeatedly input my oauth2-client-id, oauth2-client-secret and authorization-code. I copy and paste into the Terminal in Raspbian. It always says "Curl(3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL". Because I am copying and pasting all my information into the syntax, then copying and pasting the syntax into Terminal, I am at a complete loss for how to proceed.

Is something wrong with the Syntax that this Google document provided?

Google's recommended syntax is shown in the image and on the website I gave a link to.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EZ6r.png)

Comment: Can you show at least an example of the curl command you are entering? This might help others in evaluating where the problem lies.

Comment: The syntax is in the image. I took a screen shot from Google's instructions. I can not put my actual information in the fields, as that would display my ID client secret code to the world.

Answer (score 1):

.... made some progress here.
Rather than utilising the copy-code from Google, directly from the page, I copied and pasted onto "TextMate" and joined the 5 rows command into a single row.
I basically went at the beginning of each row (in TextMate) and backspace'd to the previous row, until the command was a single line one.
I then copied the single line command and pasted it into Terminal.

This is removing the previous error, at least the command is going through, I get most of the responses from the server.

I am still getting an error, which I am trying to figure out: "error" : "unsupported_grant_type".

The command includes "... grant_type=authorization_code..." within the command.

Comment: Kindly, read the help pages I linked to in your other Answer. Stack Overflow works in a  Question / Answer format. Your Answer should be complete without questions. Please note that you can edit your Answer too. Unless you have two separate answers that answers the post, you should edit your post instead of adding a new post.